# Provide vibration feedback based on whether the checkbox are checked or not

Tags: android, checkbox, checked, vibration

I am trying to developing a setting list for my app and basically I wanna have a checkbox in my settings which allow user to decide whether or not to allow vibration in the app.

To implement vibration effect in my app when the checkbox is checked is quite simple but I just could not find a way to give user instant vibration feedback when user is checking the checkbox in setting. Specifically speaking, I wanna the device vibrate when the user check the checkbox and of course dont vibrate when the user uncheck it.

Below is my checkbox preference block which should be very commom:
[image]

And the preference class which load the preference xml:

[image]

Please anyone kindly tell me how could I achieve this. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setOnPreferenceChangeListener() as below,

```
 public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{

    Vibrator v;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        v = (Vibrator) UserSettingActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("keypress_vibration");//key name in preference xml

        checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener()
        {
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)
            {
                if (newValue.toString().equals("true"))
                {
                    v.vibrate(500);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and do not forget to give permission in menifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Hope this helped!